# How to write two y lables keeping one xtick on subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot two different values and would like to show in a single subplot. Both should share same `xticks` and `xlabel`. I want to show write `y1 label` on left side and `y2 label` on right side of the plot. Plotting of single values resulted in good plot and I have set `xticks` as required. But when I try to plot the second set of values with new subplot using following second line all the `xticks` (dates) are gone. It overwrites with its own values which are not required.

```
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1 = ax.twinx() #  <-- problem line
```

How do I plot the second axis with keeping the same `xticks` plotted earlier by the previous subplot?

**Edit 1**

To make the things clear I can explain again in simple term. How can plot two sets of values and two lables on left and right side. Finally change the `xticks` with different values.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: Can you post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of code that doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Could you add an image showing what you are trying to achieve?